# Choice of caching a database result?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, caching

I want data queried from several heterogeneous databases, and joined to 1k~1m rows of results each time. in order to improve the performance, I want to add a cache for the result data. because the user may do some sorting or filtering on the result data as well, I would like to cache the results to a relational-database-like system, rather than KV-cache(memcached)

Is there any good tools for this kind of usage? IMHO, mysql has good read performance, but its write performance is not suited as a cache system, is that true?

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate caches automatically, but I've been in this situation before and caching isn't the way to go: It adds more problems than it solves, and usually only briefly delays the inevitable change of technology to... a NoSQL database approach.

Try lucene or mongodb, and store the data fully denormalized in there. You won't be sorry.

Comment: I use multi-database approach because the denormalized data would cause storage explosion in my case. would you like to share some troubles you faced when using cache in this situation? really appreciate that.

Comment: Well doesn't have to be *fully* denormalhzed, but you want to get as close to ready to render documents as you can from the NoSQL db. It's a speed at the expense of storage thing. One big problem about caching is statefullness, which goes against scaleability. With everything in a NoSQL, you can run lots of them in parallel to scale up to any load, especially in the cloud. I had no problems with it.